# jquery selection problem excluding cells in lower divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a treeview that renders as tables. The html would be something like:

```
<div id="tree">
  <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
  <div>
    <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
  </div>
  <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
  <div>
    <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
  </div>
  <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
  <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
  <div>
    <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a class to all the cells in the tables directly under div 'tree', but exclude the cells from the tables that are in a lower div.

Id's and such of the lower divs are created automatically so I cannot use these.

What I have gotten so far is

```
$('#tree table td').addClass('custom');
```

which just adds the class to all the cells. But I am stuck on how to exclude this.

Thanks for reading and hopefully lending a hand ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('#tree > table td').addClass('custom');
```

It selects all direct children of the parent element.

Comment: Yes yes thank you very much. Seems I have to read up on more of the basics of jquery :( At first it seemed not to work but I had missed there was a topdiv rendered autmatically. Now I have to add another class to the third cell but I am sure I can get there with nth-child ;)